# Save Numbered Variable

Tags: python, list

I want to save my list to numbered variable.

```
myList =[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I want save be like this :

```
numb1 = myList[1]
numb2 = myList[2]
numb3 = myList[3]
numb4 = myList[4]
numb5 = myList[5]
```

I don't want do it manually, because myList contains many elements.
Can you give me suggestion?

Comment: One problem you'll have is that Python list indexing begins at 0, not 1.  So in your example, you are ignoring the first element, `myList[0]`, and you'll get an index out-of-range error when attempting to access `mylist[5]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: "I want to save my list to numbered variable." This defeats the _entire purpose_ of the `list` type.

Comment: I can't even close this as a duplicate of ["variable variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python) because at least that one wanted to use heterogeneous names. This, however, is just a fake `list`. There is no reason to do any of this. Use a `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do this via [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> myList =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> for index, value in enumerate(myList, start=1):
...     globals()['numb'+str(index)] = value
...     
... 
>>> numb1
1
>>> numb2
2
>>> numb3
3
>>> numb10
10
>>>
```

But I'd recommend use another dict instead of [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```
>>> myList =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> d = {}
>>> for index, value in enumerate(myList, start=1):
...     d['numb'+str(index)] = value
...     
... 
>>> d['numb1']
1
>>> d['numb2']
2
>>> d['numb10']
10
>>>
```

Comment: Of course there's still the question of whether d['numb10'] has any advantage over myList[9].

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: I think that's an OP's typo, however `numb5 = myList[5]` raise an error in this case as Tom said in comments. I'm sure that OP wants `numb5 = myList[4]` which gives `numb5 == 5`. Also `numb1 = myList[0]` which gives `numb1 == 1`.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik - Indeed, there is no advantage to doing that. There are only disadvantages. Referring to a series of homogeneous objects is the whole point of a `list`.

Comment: Using `globals()` to create a series of numbered references in a horrifying mimicry of a `list` is generally a good indicator that something is very wrong.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I'd say so, so if OP really want to `'numb1'` to get `myList[1]`, then use another dict instead of `globals()` as I said in answer.

Comment: It's numbered. That is a `list`. If they want to use the phrase `numb` in there, they should make a new reference `numb = myList` and then they can do `numb[0]`. If they want the indexing to start with `1` (for no good reason), they can put `None` as the first element with `numb = [None] + myList`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Ah, however no idea about what's OP trying to do. But, isn't it a good idea about use a dict instead of `numb = [None] + myList` if OP wants use `numb1` to get `myList[0]`? I think it would be little slow if the list is large.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in which problem X (i.e., referring to elements in a `list`) is much easier than problem Y (i.e., creating a series of numbered variables corresponding to elements in a `list`). On top of that, doing this would defeat the entire purpose of using a `list`. It doesn't take too long to hard-code it for the five elements you showed, but the `list` with "many elements" you mention should *not* be given this treatment.

A `list` holds several objects, generally of a homogeneous type and purpose, like inches of rainfall on each day of the year. This data structure makes it easy to store and process all of these objects together. You can also refer to them individually, by indexing.

Where you are hoping to refer to the first element of `myList` as `numb1`, use instead `myList[0]`. That is the reference that you already have for that object. You do *not* need to pollute the namespace with a pile of numbered references. The `list` type is intended precisely for this situation. Please use a `list`.